# TYPO3 CMS V9: How to batch import userdata with one-time password into fe_users table?

Tags: typo3, password-encryption, typo3-9.x

I have to import many thousands of userdata into fe_users table. The problem is that the userdata include one-time passwords which are set elsewhere.

Is there a way to import and salt the passwords automatically?

(In former times this happened after the first login, but this seems not to be possible any more. I remember that some years ago there was a scheduler task to do this, but this seems to have disappeared, somehow?)

Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We decided not to use the passwords. As long as the userdata contain the real email adresses, (which they do), the users can use the password-forgotten-function to set their own passwords.

Comment: That would be my suggestion, too. Reset the passwords and let the users know how to set a new password. You can sell it with improved security.